# How do I force jQuery append to NOT automatically close a tag?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a JavaScript object with about 1000 properties and want to create a `<table>` of these entries, with eight properties in a single row, `<tr>`.

I am using jQuery `append()`; however, it is automatically appending a closing `</tr>` tag. I want to manually define where the closing `</tr>` should go. How do I accomplish this?

The object:

```
var g2u = {};

g2u.a1 = "&#xe000;";
g2u.a2 = "&#xe001;";
g2u.a3 = "&#xe002;";
g2u.a4 = "&#xe003;";
g2u.a5 = "&#xe004;";
g2u.a5a = "&#xe005;";
g2u.a6 = "&#xe006;";
g2u.a6a = "&#xe007;";
g2u.a6b = "&#xe008;";
... etc...
```

The `<table>`:

```
<table id="list" border="1">
</table>

<script>
var ctr = 0;
$("#list").append('<tr>');

for (var g in g2u) {
  $("#list").append('<td><span class="rom">'+g+'</span>\n');
  $("#list").append('<span class="eh">'+g2u[g]+'</span>\n');
  $("#list").append('<span class="rom">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>\n');
  ctr++;
  if (ctr % 8 == 0) {
    $("#list").append('</tr><tr>\n');
  }
}
```

The *broken* output:

```
<tbody><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr></tbody>
<td><span class="rom">a1</span></td><span class="eh"></span><span class="rom">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><td><span class="rom">a2</span></td><span class="eh"></span><span class="rom">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><td><span class="rom">a3</span></td><span class="eh"></span><span class="rom">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><td><span class="rom">a4</span></td><span class="eh"></span><span class="rom">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><td><span class="rom">a5</span></td><span class="eh"></span><span class="rom">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><td><span class="rom">a5a</span></td><span class="eh"></span><span class="rom">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><td><span class="rom">a6</span></td><span class="eh"></span><span class="rom">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><td><span class="rom">a6a</span></td><span class="eh"></span><span class="rom">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><td><span class="rom">a6b</span></td><span class="eh"></span><span class="rom">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><td><span class="rom">a7</span></td><span class="eh"></span><span class="rom">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><td><span class="rom">a8</span></td><span class="eh"></span><span class="rom">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><td><span class="rom">a9</span></td><span class="eh"></span><span class="rom">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><td><span class="rom">a10</span></td><span class="eh"></span><span class="rom">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><td><span class="rom">a11</span></td><span class="eh"></span><span class="rom">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><td><span class="rom">a12</span></td><span class="eh"></span><span class="rom">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><td><span class="rom">a13</span></td><span class="eh"></span><span class="rom">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><td><span class="rom">a14</span></td><span class="eh"></span><span class="rom">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><td><span class="rom">a14a</span></td><span class="eh"></span><span class="rom">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><td><spa
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you append it will obviously try to close tags.
Try to put your html in an string than append that string to the dom.

```
    <script>
    var ctr = 0;
    var html='<tr>';

    for (var g in g2u) {
      html+='<td><span class="rom">'+g+'</span>\n';
      html+='<span class="eh">'+g2u[g]+'</span>\n';
      html+='<span class="rom">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>\n';
      ctr++;
      if (ctr % 8 == 0) {
        html+='</tr><tr>\n';
      }
    }


     $("#list").append(html);
```

Comment: Simple and nice

Comment: this does not answer the question of "how to force prevention of closing tag" - this method accepted here will not work when trying to append a for a form tag to a div that contains form elements.

Answer (score 16):

You're thinking in terms of html markup, with using append you should be thinking in terms of html [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM), you don't have open tags and close tag just elements.

You can use a string to build your html then append it to the table

```
var ctr = 0;
var innerTable = '<tr>';

for (var g in g2u) {
  innerTable += '<td><span class="rom">'+g+'</span>\n';
  innerTable += '<span class="eh">'+g2u[g]+'</span>\n';
  innerTable += '<span class="rom">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>\n';
  ctr++;
  if (ctr % 8 == 0) {
    innerTable += '</tr><tr>\n';
  }
}
$("#list").append(innerTable);
```

Answer (score 7):

Seven years, but I tought I could help anyone else that comes across a similar problem. For example, if you want to use JQuery's $.each() with .append() to make an list of users, such as:

```
<ul>
  <li>User 1</li>
  <li>User 2</li>
</ul>
```

Here's what you DON'T want to do:

```
element.append(`<ul>`);
$.each(users, function(key, value) {
  element.append(`<li>${value.name}</li>`);
});
element.append(`</ul>`);
```

The output will be something like:

```
<ul></ul>
<li>User 1</li>
<li>User 2</li>
```

Instead, here's what you WANT to do:

```
element.append(`<ul id="ul-users"></ul>`);
$.each(users, function(key, value) {
  $("#ul-users").append(`<li>${value.name}</li>`);
});
```

So the output will be as follows:

```
<ul id="ul-users">
  <li>User 1</li>
  <li>User 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This was so obvious but still so helpful!