# javascript automatically closes tags in a string

Tags: javascript

This is a very weird issue

```
statements[bracket].assembly+='<expr operator="'+statements[bracket].firsthalf.mathoperator+'"><constant value="'+statements[bracket].firsthalf.constant+'" /><parameter name="'+statements[bracket].secondhalf.parameter+'"/></expr>'
```

the `statements[bracket].firsthalf.constant=2` and the message should appear as `<constant value="2" />` , but the tag is shown as `<constant value="2"></constant>` , any idea why the tag is closed automatically ?!

[image]

Comment: It's more likely that the browser is doing this, not JavaScript itself.  This could just be the browser cleaning up the DOM to match some standards.

Comment: Javascript doesn't alter a string like that. What are you doing with the string after you have put it together? What is it that you are showing in the alert?

Comment: @Guffa this is my typical code http://fiddle.jshell.net/prollygeek/AMnLS/ , and im running test on first iteration where bracket is equal to 0

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: statements is not defined` `Uncaught ReferenceError: bracket is not defined` `Cannot read property 'operator' of undefined` Can you update your fiddle or provide enough code so that the problem can be reproduced?

Answer (score 2):

You must have passed the expression through some place where the string is treated as HTML (e.g. innerHTML). The problem isn't in the string manipulation code you've shown but somewhere else.

What happens between the time you evaluate this expression to the time when you alert the  statement?

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/prollygeek/AMnLS/ , this is a typical code ryan , please check it , i didnt get your answer clearly.

Comment: even if it is treated as html , why should the tags be closed automatically ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek: because self closing tag isn't strictly a valid HTML, but commonly accepted by browsers as compatibility to XML and XHTML, so the browser tried to fix your HTML in a way it thinks is reasonable to ensure the DOM is usable. JavaScript string is just plain string, it won't treat tags inside a string in any special way, that's why your problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948853/how-do-i-force-jquery-append-to-not-automatically-close-a-tag , a similar issue was posted here

Comment: @ProllyGeek: which brought nothing new to the table. As I have already said, the browser will fix up invalid HTML before inserting it to the document. Many jquery functions such as .append() treats the item it handles as HTML and must contain well formed HTML fragment. If you want us to help you find exactly where the problem is in your code, the code you've given us so far is irrelevant to your problem. If you want us to be able to help you find the problem in your code, please produce a [short, self contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating your problem.

Comment: im trying to do so trust me

Answer (score 1):

The code doesn't produce the output that you show. Either you are actually using some other code, or you are doing something with the string (like parsing it as XML) before displaying it.

I provided the code with this data:

```
var bracket = 0;
var statements = [
    { assembly: '', operator: 'greater',
     firsthalf: { mathoperator: '*', constant: '2', parameter: '' },
     secondhalf: { mathoperator: '', constant: '2', parameter: '' }
    } ];
```

That makes the code alert this string, as expected:

```
<greater><expr operator="*"> <constant value="2" /> <parameter name=""/> </expr><parameter name=""/></greater>
```

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/AMnLS/1/