# XHTML possibly blocking jQuery method .append?

Tags: jquery, html, xhtml, append, prepend

I was trying to improve my website adding parts that will be there in every page and automatically update as i update a file: i know there are many methods but I'm still a beginner and i decided to use jQuery. The problem is that i use a `<table>` because I have a bar div that needs to be on the side of what's in the HTML. I prepended the header, the opening tags of the table (including tr and td) and their content and appended the closing of the tags. The HTML contained whatever staid near the bar: and it does! But it's under the bar: I'm not really sure what happened: my thought was that XHTML was closing the tags automatically before appending since in the HTML it didn't find them... I'll include the code that we're interested it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').prepend('<table><tr><td>Text</td><td>');
    $('body').append('</td></tr></table>');
})
```

That is the jQuery code and i can ensure you i have proper links to the script and to jQuery (+UI) which work. Now everything should be simple: you just add your HTML code in the  of the .html file... But nope!

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Cheese</title>
      <script to my script and jQuery library/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- here should go what I prepended, and it does,
           but closes the <table></td></tr> tags aswell -->
      This should be to the side of 'Text' and comprehended in the table, in a td
      <!-- here should go what I appended,
           but strangely it doesn't -->
   </body>
</html>
```

Have I done anything wrong? if you don't see anything wrong here I'll send you all of the code, thank you in advance!

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948853/how-do-i-force-jquery-append-to-not-automatically-close-a-tag

Comment: Wait are you trying to put the contents of the page body in a table cell?

Comment: My goal is to put everything inside the body on the side of the Text... so i can have a stable menu that doesn't need to be added manually for every page... i thought it was the compacter way, do you suggest anything else? Or do you know a fix for removing the auto-closing tags?

Comment: You should be using PHP for this, not jQuery

Comment: PHP is to easy to break when you have inputs... at least... i know it was... and can you even link to a php script? And i don't think i'd like to learn another language in some time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot append/prepend/insert tags into the DOM only complete html elements. When you pass partial fragments of html to be inserted into the DOM the browser(or maybe jquery) does the best it can with it.
What you should do is build a table with the descried content and insert that to the dom

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').html('<table><tr><td>Text</td><td>'+$('body').html()+'</td></tr></table>');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yY92d/

Comment: sorry Musa... it actually displays what I want on the side of the bar... but what if I did not only have `text`, but `pre`s, `input`s and other stuff? Sorry for my noobness... but I started learning jQuery 3 days ago and been travelling a lot... I'm still learning... what should i use instead of `.text()`? This is what it gives me [link](http://www.copot.eu/matei): all of those `@` are in fact a pre, and the text coming after it are various divs that i used to make tabs to inputs using jQuery... Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: Oh right... i could have thought about that myself... Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: @Musa I highly recommend you give warnings about what is good and bad practice. The OP now swears by this code because it "works" and has a 16 second page load time. I kid you not.