# Ajax appending data to existing table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Been at this for a while and I'm stuck.  Trying to display data from a table and on the same page, theres an entry form to add data to the table.

script

```
$(function(){
var url = '<?php echo base_url();?>assets/includes/em_report_get_intervals.php';
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, data) {
    $('#tablebody').append('<tr>');
    $('#tablebody').append('<td>'+data.em_service_level+'</td>');
    $('#tablebody').append('<td>'+data.em_speed_of_answer+'</td>');
    $('#tablebody').append('<td>'+data.em_volume+'</td>');
    $('#tablebody').append('</tr>');
    });
});

$('#myForm').on('submit',function(e) {  
    $.ajax({
        url:'<?php echo base_url();?>assets/includes/em_report_write_interval.php',
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        type:'POST',
        success:function(data){

            var em_service_level = $('#em_service_level').val();
            var em_speed_of_answer = $('#em_speed_of_answer').val();
            var em_volume = $('#em_volume').val();

            $('#tablebody').append('<tr>');
            $('#tablebody').append('<td>'+em_service_level+'</td>');
            $('#tablebody').append('<td>'+em_speed_of_answer+'</td>');
            $('#tablebody').append('<td>'+em_volume+'</td>');
            $('#tablebody').append('</tr>');            
        },
        error:function(data){
        $("#error").show().fadeOut(5000); //===Show Error Message====
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});});
```

Table to display records

```
<table class="table_data">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>em_service_level</th>
   <th>em_speed_of_answer</th>
   <th>em_volume</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="tablebody">
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Entry form

```
<form class="form2" action="" method="POST" name="myForm" id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="em_service_level" class="text_box" size="20" value="<?php echo set_value('em_service_level');?>" />
  <input type="text" name="em_speed_of_answer" class="text_box" size="20" value="<?php echo set_value('em_speed_of_answer');?>" />
  <input type="text" name="em_volume" class="text_box" size="20" value="<?php echo set_value('em_volume');?>" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit_interval" id="submit_interval" class="normal_button" value="Add Interval" />
</form>
```

em_report_write_interval.php

```
if(isset($_POST['em_service_level']))
{
$em_service_level   = $_POST['em_service_level'];
$em_speed_of_answer = $_POST['em_speed_of_answer'];
$em_volume          = $_POST['em_volume'];

$query = "
    INSERT INTO ajax_test(
        `em_service_level`,
        `em_speed_of_answer`,
        `em_volume`
        ) VALUES (
        '$em_service_level',
        '$em_speed_of_answer',
        '$em_volume'
        )";

mysql_query($query);
}
```

Now the problem I have is this all technically works except when I add data into the form.  It appends to the table but instead of the values I add, all I see is "undefined" until I refresh the page.  Then the values show.

This code is hacked from examples I've found and am trying to make work so please forgive my sloppiness.

Comment: Don't break the html up into individual open tr, td, td...close tr. Combine all of those to a single string and $().append that.

Comment: you will be getting "undefined" because the value wasn't found - as I see now that Andrei has explained properly.

Comment: Similiar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948853/how-do-i-force-jquery-append-to-not-automatically-close-a-tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `name`, not the id. So need to correct the selectors:

```
var em_service_level = $('input[name="em_service_level"]').val();
var em_speed_of_answer = $('input[name="em_speed_of_answer"]').val();
var em_volume = $('input[name="em_volume"]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your form you have:

```
<input type="text" name="em_service_level" 
class="text_box" size="20" 
value="<?php echo set_value('em_service_level');?>" />
```

In the ajax callback function you try to select these as if they had an id attribute, whereas they don't.

So, change your element and add an id, or change your jquery selector. The former is easier. For the first input you'd get:

```
                                           |
                                           v
<input type="text" name="em_service_level" id="em_service_level"
class="text_box" size="20" 
value="<?php echo set_value('em_service_level');?>" />
```