# Why does Firefox change form tag attribute when loaded from javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form that's being created using Javascript. I am storing the form in a string variable then using append to add the variable to the page (I did it this way because append was [closing tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948853/how-do-i-force-jquery-append-to-not-automatically-close-a-tag) before they had actual data). When I load the page in Chrome, everything looks fine. In Firefox, the  tag is altered.

This is the proper formatting of the form tag:

```
<form class="form-horizontal luminateApi survey-form" method="POST" action="http://demand.convio.net/site/CRSurveyAPI" data-luminateApi="{"callback": "submitSurveyCallback", "requiresAuth": "true"}">
```

Firefox changes it to this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal luminateApi survey-form" method="POST" action="http://demand.convio.net/site/CRSurveyAPI" data-luminateapi="{" callback":="" "submitsurveycallback",="" "requiresauth":="" "true"}"="">
```

It works in Chrome.

Comment: The value of an attribute that starts with `"` ends at the next `"`. I'm very surprised it works differently in Chrome, I suspect you made a mistake thinking it did.

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery's `.data()` to add the data attribute?

Comment: I just tried it with Chrome, it did the same as FF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes for the content of the attributes:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal luminateApi survey-form" method="POST" action="http://demand.convio.net/site/CRSurveyAPI" data-luminateApi="{'callback': 'submitSurveyCallback', 'requiresAut': 'true'}">
```

Otherwise a browser must interpret the content as separate attributes.

Comment: Not just might, **must**. The double quote ends the attribute value.

Comment: @Barmar you are right, I edit the post to reflect that.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!