# jQuery appending JSON data to table keeps putting elements in the wrong place

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I would like to create a table with the the JSON data I retrieved from my API, but jQuery keeps putting elements in the wrong place....

This is my jQuery code:

```
var container = $("#container");
var table = $("#table");

$(document).ready(function() {
    callAPI();
});

function callAPI() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "action-api.php",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {   
            console.log(data);
            container.append('<table style="width:100%"><tr><th>ID</th><th>Naam</th> <th>Brouwerij</th><th>Type</th><th>Gisting</th><th>Percentage</th><th>Inkoop Prijs</th></tr>');

            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                container.append('<tr><td>' + item.id + '</td>');
                container.append('<td>' + item.naam + '</td>');
                container.append('<td>' + item.brouwerij + '</td>');
                container.append('<td>' + item.type + '</td>');
                container.append('<td>' + item.gisting + '</td>');
                container.append('<td>' + item.perc + '</td>');
                container.append('<td>' + item.inkoop_prijs + '</td></tr>');
            });

            container.append('</table>');
        },  
    });
}
```

This is the HTML output:

[image: HTML OUTPUT]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've to create the `table` and the row `tr` separated of the `td`, else they will be closed automatically after the append, for example when you do :

```
container.append('<tr><td>' + item.id + '</td>');
```

The output will be :

```
<tr><td>item.id</td></tr>
____________________^^^^^ //NOTE the closed tag will be added automatically
```

So you have just to separate them like :

```
var table = $('<table style="width:100%"></table>');

table.append('<tr><th>ID</th><th>Naam</th> <th>Brouwerij</th><th>Type</th><th>Gisting</th><th>Percentage</th><th>Inkoop Prijs</th></tr>');

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    var tr = $('<tr/>');

    tr.append('<td>' + item.id + '</td>');
    tr.append('<td>' + item.naam + '</td>');
    tr.append('<td>' + item.brouwerij + '</td>');
    tr.append('<td>' + item.type + '</td>');
    tr.append('<td>' + item.gisting + '</td>');
    tr.append('<td>' + item.perc + '</td>');
    tr.append('<td>' + item.inkoop_prijs + '</td>');

    table.append(tr);
});

container.append(table);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just create your whole bloc and then append it :

```
var container = $("#container");
var table = $("#table");

$(document).ready(function() {
    callAPI();
});

function callAPI() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "action-api.php",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {   
            console.log(data);
            var html = '<table style="width:100%"><tr><th>ID</th><th>Naam</th> <th>Brouwerij</th><th>Type</th><th>Gisting</th><th>Percentage</th><th>Inkoop Prijs</th></tr>';

            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                html+='<tr><td>' + item.id + '</td>';
                html+='<td>' + item.naam + '</td>';
                html+='<td>' + item.brouwerij + '</td>';
                ...
            });

            html+='</table>';
          container.append(html);
        },  
    });
}
```

Here is the explanation for this: [How do I force jQuery append to NOT automatically close a tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948853/how-do-i-force-jquery-append-to-not-automatically-close-a-tag)

Comment: Tested yours too and your answer is valid too, thank you very much!

Comment: No problem! Regards