# Jquery closing tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a script in which I am using div tag inside the jquery code. Now what is happening that, whever  tag appeas in the jquery code it automatically closing the script tag and breaks the jquery code.
Suppose I have the following code:

```
<script>var b = 25;var h = '<div>here is the problem</div>';var c= 5;var d =6;</script>
```

Now when I see the output on browser I got this var c=5; var d=6;
as `</div>` is encounter means this `'</'` which closes the script tag by `</script>`

This is the code
http://prntscr.com/f0lv13

This is the output
http://prntscr.com/f0lv8z

This is the chrome console
http : // prntscr.com/f0lw2t

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I force jQuery append to NOT automatically close a tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948853/how-do-i-force-jquery-append-to-not-automatically-close-a-tag)

Comment: Wow .. that's quite some code ... can you create a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (click link) ... or at least highlight the problem section ?

Comment: Where? That is a mountain of code with no indication of where the problem is. You problem is probably related to mismatch quotes somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I believe you made a typo over there and instead of closing `</script>`, you have `</scipt>`

try this:

```
<script>var b = 25;var h = '<div>here is the problem</div>';var c= 5;var d =6;</script>
```

Comment: This is the code
http://prntscr.com/f0lv13

This is the output
http://prntscr.com/f0lv8z